# Slow VB6 String Operations on Windows 7

Tags: performance, windows-7, vb6

We have a VB6 program that does some string processing in a loop (approximately 500 times) and appends info to a textbox. Each iteration on the loop includes basic operations like Trim, Len, Left, Mid, etc, and finally appends the string to a textbox (the whole form is still invisible at this point). Finally, after the loop, the code calls Show on the form.

On Windows XP, these 500 loops take about 4 seconds. On Windows 7, the exact same code runs in about 90 seconds.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm desperately resisting the temptation to provide the immediate and obvious response of "Ditch the VB6 app..."  (even though that's really the best answer).

Comment: Be sure you are using the string form of the functions, Trim$, Left$, Mid$. They are faster than the variant versions without the $.

Comment: How exactly are you appending to the text box? `textbox.text = textbox.text & "blah"` is VERY inefficient! Oh, and showing us the code you're using means we may have a hope of helping you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you append the text box on each loop iteration... If you can, store everything in a variable and append it to the `TextBox` once after the loop is finished. Displaying text in a text box takes a lot of time in VB6.

EDIT:
After further investigation and testing, I came to a conclusion that performance on directly assigning strings to the `Text` property of a `TextBox` degrades dramatically when the length of the control reaches maximum. The maximum on my PC is 65535 for some reason, even though according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) its

> **Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000, Windows 2000 Professional, Windows 2000 Server, Windows 2000 Advanced Server, Windows XP Home Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows Server 2003 Platform Note:** For single line text box controls, if the **MaxLength** property is set to 0, the maximum number of characters the user can enter is 2147483646 or an amount based on available memory, whichever is smaller

Basically what seems to be happening, if you keep adding text to the `TextBox` each iteration, it isn't that slow until you reach maximum. What's even more puzzling, when you try to add text beyond the maximum, there will be no errors, but performance degrades significantly.

In my test loop I go from 0 to 12773 I have this:

`Text2.Text = Text2.Text + CStr(a) + " "`

So when the loop is completed in 4 seconds, the `Text2.Text` is 65534 characters long. Now, when I double the loop to go beyond the maximum allowed length of the `TextBox`, it takes three times as much time to complete it.

12773 - 4 seconds

12773*2 - 16 seconds

After realizing this, my first thought was to replace the `TextBox` with a `RichTextBox`. But the performance of the latter is even worse. This is assuming you update it every iteration.

It seems that you are stuck with a dilemma - suffer slow performance or change the code to update text box only once after the loop is completed. Further, due to `TextBox`'s maximum length limit, I recommend switching to a `RichTextBox` or depending on the purpose of this - some other object.

I hope my findings are helpful - it has certainly been fun finding out all these little programming quirks.

Comment: We have the whole thing hidden while this is happening...and moreover, we've applied the fix mentioned by MarkJ which should mean it's not displaying anything.

Comment: For a loop to 500 both methods are sufficient. I am however a performance-oriented freak so I tested both methods with a simple loop from 0 to 30000. The method with textbox updates (implementing MarkJ's method) every iteration takes a total 20 seconds to complete. Memory storing way takes only 2 seconds to finish. I have the code if you are curious about this.

Comment: +1. By the way, the VB6 documentation [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445728(v=vs.60).aspx) that the limit of a `Text` property on a `TextBox` control is about 32k characters. Half what you've found - maybe the VB6 docs are quoting some lower bound that applied on Windows 98 or something, but there's another limit.

Comment: this is weird... from the link you provided > ***The Text setting for a TextBox control is limited to 2048 characters unless the MultiLine property is True, in which case the limit is about 32K.*** IN that line `Text` property is maximum 2048 characters long... unless `MultiLine` is set to `True`. In my tests, `MultiLine=False` and `MaxLength=0` and yet the length of the `TextBox` was 65535. I'm on Win 7 64-bit. Perhaps someone could test this on another machine? Preferably 32-bit?

Answer (score 2):

Try [LockWindowUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to switch off updating for your form.

```
 Declare Function LockWindowUpdate Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long 

'To turn it on just call it like this, passing it the hWnd of the window to lock. 
LockWindowUpdate Form1.hWnd

'intensive updating here

 'to turn it off just call it and pass it a zero.
 LockWindowUpdate 0
```

From [here](http://www.ex-designz.net/apidetail.asp?api_id=203)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, we tried this suggestion. It did not work for us. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user1231160 Try [user1655087's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12590560/15639). Maybe with a [VB6 stringbuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12590560/15639) from Karl Peterson

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you find out exactly what is slow. Redo your timings before and after the string concatenation, and then before and after the copy of the string into the text box. Have the Ole Automation string operations somehow become slower, or has the copying of text into a VB text box become slower?

Once you know this, we can continue with phase 2 ... :-)